# Polymer: this.setAttribute() is not a function

Tags: javascript, data-binding, polymer

So I'm trying to get some Polymer databinding to work but for some reason the below code gives me a `TypeError: this.setAttribute is not a function(…)`

I've tried replacing `this.setAttribute('display', 1);` with `this.display = 1;` but that doesn't seem to work either.

What am I doing wrong?

```
Polymer({
  is: 'unibz-club',

  properties: {
    display:{
      type: Number,
      notify: true,
      value: 0,
    }
  },
  ready: function() {
    this.setAttribute('display', 1);    //  <--not working
  }.bind(this),
};
```

Comment: Well, one thing to note is that you're missing a closing parenthesis before the ending semicolon.

Comment: Why are you explicitly binding 'this'? I believe 'ready' method already has a this context that refers to the Polymer object being instantiated. Right now, you're probably changing the context to the window or containing closure.

Comment: Sorry, the parentheses is closed in my code but the tip with binding "this" did it! Could you explain to me when i need tho bind "this" and when I don't? I can't seem to find a good explanation...

Comment: Oh and thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The 'ready' method already has a `this` context that refers to the Polymer object being instantiated. Right now, you're changing the context to the window or containing closure with the `.bind(this)` call.

The Polymer library is handling this for you. It will invoke the 'ready' method in the context of the newly created object.

You would typically use `.bind()` to define the context of `this` in callback methods and then-able promises. There are of course other uses but this is most common in my experience.

```
function ImageLoader () {
    return this;
}

ImageLoader.prototype.load = function(path) {
    return ajaxService.get(path);    
};

function Gallery () {
    this.images = [];
    return this;
}

Gallery.prototype.init = function() {
    new ImageLoader().load('/photos/gallery').then(function(result) {
        this.images = result; 
    }.bind(this)); // <-- .bind(this) will set the context of `this` to the Gallery instance
};

var gallery = new Gallery();
gallery.init();
```

Comment: Thank you! This helped me a lot!